# What is the mongoose schema of this json example?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a Node.js  project with MongoDb Database   .
 I need the schema of this json example  :

I am working on a Node.js  project with MongoDb Database   .
 I need the schema of this json example

MongoDb document :

```
{
  "container_number": "ddd",
  "container_Date": "2/2/2018",
  "scannedProductArray": {
    "CCR": [
      {
        "ScannedDate": {
          "$date": "2018-03-28T20:54:57.663Z"
        },
        "productNumber": "4656874974",
        "productType": "CCR"
      },
      {
        "ScannedDate": {
          "$date": "2018-03-28T20:55:23.698Z"
        },
        "productNumber": "4656874974",
        "productType": "CCR"
      }
    ],
    "CCH": [
      {
        "ScannedDate": {
          "$date": "2018-03-28T21:25:16.202Z"
        },
        "productNumber": "4656874974",
        "productType": "CCR"
      },
      {
        "ScannedDate": {
          "$date": "2018-03-28T21:26:08.696Z"
        },
        "productNumber": "4656874974",
        "productType": "CCR"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
container_number: String,
container_Date: String,
scannedProductArray:{CCR:[ScannedDate: {
          date:type:Date,default:Date.now
        },
        "productNumber:Number,
        "productType": "String"],CCH[:[ScannedDate: {
          date:type:Date,default:Date.now
        },
        "productNumber:Number,
        "productType": "String"]}
```

May be this one helps you.

Comment: I need scannedProductArray to be dynamic , CCR and CCH is an example , I need to add dynamic elements to the object scannedProductArray

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to define schemas like this:

```
const Product = {
    ScannedDate: {
        type: Object,
    },
    productNumber: {
        type: String,
    },
    productType: {
        type: String,
        default: 'CCR',
    }
};
const Item = {
    itemName: {
        type: [Product],
    },
};
const Container = {
    container_number: {
        type: String,
    },
    container_Date: {
        type: String
    },
    scannedProductArray: {
        type: Object, // Item
    }
};
```

If the `CCR`/`CCH` fields are dynamic, I can just use `type: Object` rather than a certain structure. And I validate these array items by myself instead of mongoose.

Comment: yes  scannedProductArray and the elements inside it  are dynamic (cch,ccr,mmc.hhj,....)elements   , also . every element in scannedProductArray  is an array of  predefined schema , 
but the problem with scannedProductArray schema to defined